# Access Query Expression: Extract word between two other words

Tags: string, ms-access, expression

Hi there:  I've checked several solutions now and I'm close but not quite there. However, I'm also trying to determine if what I'm doing makes sense. I just keep feeling like there's a better option.

Business problem: I need to extract the Region Name, which is between the word "DID " and " Region".  I've been able to do either one to get everything before and the Region Name and the word "Region", but I want just the Region Name.  Please see below and advise - very much appreciated!

Example:  DID North Region.  I only want "North".

```
Region: IIf(Right([Tier 6],6)="Region",Mid([Tier 6],InStrRev([Tier 6],"DID ")+4),"")
```

This expression gives me [Region Name] Region.  I want the word "Region" removed as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using IIf conditional, I presume "Region" is not always present. Also presume if there is no "Region" then there is no "DID". In case there is possibility field will be null, consider:

`Region: IIf(InStr(Nz([Tier 6],""),"Region")>0,Mid(Left([Tier 6],InStrRev([Tier 6]," ")-1),5),[Tier 6])`

Comment: Thank you June7. I will try this shortly!

Comment: Ah - I always forget something!  I failed to mention that there will be characters before the "DID". And to answer your question, the "DID" and "Region" are not in all instances, so I was using Region to narrow down my search. Anything else I wanted "".

Comment: But the good thing is that the code works for omitting "Region". Thank you!  I think I will take what I had initially and mash it with yours so that it omits the "DID" as well. Wish me luck!

Comment: Well, June7, this is the result I came up with, and again, thanks for your help!  It's a bit muddy, but seems to work. = )  Region: IIf(InStr(Nz([Tier 6],""),"Region")>0,Replace(Mid([Tier 6],InStrRev([Tier 6],"DID ")+4)," Region",""),"")